# jquery.simplyscroll.min.js and JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have very little JavaScript experience so please bear with me - I've taken over an MVC 5 application from a colleague, and I needed to use the tabs feature from http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
To do this I added the three lines headed @*Jquery tabs*@ to the head element of my _Layout.cshtml, with the result that I have a tabs control that works, but I've also introduced jQuery undefined error with regards to jquery.simplyscroll.min.js. I've pasted the head element below. I can see I'm using multiple jquery-[version here].min.js but it didn't seem possible to get the tabs control without using 1.4.4.

Here's my head element:

```
@*    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.simplyscroll.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domainserver/cdn/css/jquery-ui.1.9.2.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://domainserver/css/osx.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
@*Jquery tabs*@
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("head", false)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, haven't been at work today but will try it first thing tomorrow morning and post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Jquery script reference up...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then add this...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.simplyscroll.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The *simplyscroll* will depend on jquery, and you're loading the jquery library after the *simplyscroll*